# undefined method `new' for nil:NilClass - what's wrong with has_one nested association in rails 3.1.0?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1

There are quote and test_plan in our app. The relationship is quote has_one test_plan and test_plan belongs_to a quote. In routes file it is:

```
  resources :test_plans, :only => [:index]
  resources :quotes do
    resources :test_plans
  end
```

The problem is that @quote.test_plan returns nil (instead of an object) and @quote.test_plan.new() causes error saying undefined method new(). Any thoughts about the problem? Thanks so much.

Answer (score 3):

```
@test_plan = @quote.build_test_plan
```

creates a @test_plan object with foreign key set by @quote. This solves the problem.

Comment: There you go! I'm deleting my answer because you answered it better yourself. I'd use the singular form in the nested resource, though (resource :test_plan). That eliminates unnecessary ids from your routes. You go from /quotes/1/test_plans/1 to /quotes/1/test_plan.